# Replace the separator between pairs of numbers

Tags: regex, linux, string, shell, sed

I want to replace all strings like `[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]` with `[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]` using `sed`.

In other words, I want to replace `-` with `/`.

If I have somewhere in my text:

```
09-36
32-43
54-65
```

I want this change:

```
09/36
32/43
54/65
```

Answer (score 3):

Using GNU `sed`:

```
$ echo '09-36 32-43 54-65' | sed -r 's|\<([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})\>|\1/\2|g'
09/36 32/43 54/65
```

- `-r` turns on *extended* regular expressions, which:

  - doesn't require `\`-escaping `( ) { }` char.
  - enables use of `\<` and `/>` to only match at word boundaries (if the expression should only match full lines, use `^` and `$` instead, and omit the `g` option)
- `|` is used as an alternative regex delimiter so that `/` can be used without `\`-escaping.

<sup>A BSD/macOS `sed` solution would look slightly different:

`echo '09-36 32-43 54-65' | sed -E 's|[[:<:]]([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})[[:>:]]|\1/\2|g'`</sup>

Comment: Far better than my version without -r

Comment: @BenjaminPodszun: Thanks. Your version has the advantage of being POSIX-compliant, though (but that precludes use of advanced features like word-boundary assertions).

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e 's/\([0-9]\{2\}\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\1\/\2/g'
```

Might not be the most elegant version, but works for me. The gazillion backslashes make this rather unreadable in my opinion. You might improve the readability by *not* using / to separate the pattern and the replacement maybe?

Comment: Less backslashes with `sed -re 's#([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})#\1/\2#g`

Comment: @WalterA It's worth noticing that `-r` is a GNU extension to enable ERA regex. BSD uses `-E` which is also supported by GNU, but it is not mentioned anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -C -npe 's/(?<!\d)(\d\d)-(\d\d)(?!\d)/\1\/\2/g' file
```

*Input*

```
维基 1-11 22-33 444-44 55-555 66-66百科
77-77
8 88-88
```

*Output*

```
维基 1-11 22/33 444-44 55-555 66/66百科
77/77
8 88/88
```

---

In the command above

- `-C` enables Unicode;
- `-n` causes Perl to process the script for each input line;
- `-p` causes Perl to print the result of the script to the standard output;
- `-e` accepts a Perl expression (particularly, it is a substitution).

In this mode (`-npe`), Perl works just like *sed*. The script substitutes each pair of digits separated with `-` to the same pair separated with a slash.

`(?<!\d)` and `(?!\d)` are negative [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) expressions.

---

To edit the file in place use `-i` option: `perl -C -i.backup -npe ...`.

---

If the input is not a file, you can pass the input to Perl via pipe, e.g.:

```
echo '维基 1-11 22-33 444-44 55-555 66-66百科' | \
  perl -C -npe 's/(?<!\d)(\d\d)-(\d\d)(?!\d)/\1\/\2/g'
```

Comment: ++ for use of the look-around assertions `(?<!\d)` and `(?!\d)` to disambiguate the matches.